# Adding values to certain keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, parsing

I have a data set that is currently a dictionary like so:

```
["Test Suite #1"], ["unnecessary info"], ["tc1"], ["tc2"], ["tc3"], ["unnecessary info"], 
 ["Test Suite #2"], ["unnecessary info"], ["tc4"], ["tc5"], ["tc6"], ["unnecessary info"]
```

I want to extract from this data set the "Test Suite #" (so the key) and just the necessary data from that Test Suite (all the items with "tc"). So what I did was have some for loops to iterate through the data:

```
for key, value in data.items(): 
    new_data_set = {}
    new_data_set.update({key: ''})
    for items in value: 
        if tc_flag in items:        #this flag basically looks for items with tc
          new_dict.update({key:items})
```

This produces the output of:

```
{Test Suite#1: [tc1], Test Suite#2: [tc4]}
```

But I want to produce an output like so:

```
{Test Suite#1: [tc1], [tc2], [tc3], Test Suite#2: [tc4], [tc5], [tc6]}
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: It's really helpful in questions to use the actual syntax of the language in examples. It's not really clear what you are starting with because `{Test Suite #1: [unnecessary info], [tc1], [tc2], [tc3], [unnecessary info], ...` is not valid python. Is that supposed to be a list of lists?

Comment: +1 @MarkMeyer, if applicable, @brobi10 please provide a mimimal pythonic definition of `data` so we can play around and give you hints.

Comment: Yes sorry its supposed to be a list of lists.

Comment: If it is list of list, your code has no sense, has it uses a dict structure, please clarify, and put the real things, and your code with the real output

Answer (score 0):

You want, as value, as list, you need to append each element, not replace the previous one , make a list at each iteration to keep the things you need

```
data = {"Test Suite  # 1": ["unnecessary info", "tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "unnecessary info"],
        "Test Suite  # 2": ["unnecessary info", "tc4", "tc5", "tc6", "unnecessary info"]}
new_dict = {}
tc_flag = "tc"
for key, value in data.items():
    keep_values = []
    for items in value:
        if tc_flag in items:  # this flag basically looks for items with tc
            keep_values.append(items)
    new_dict[key] = keep_values

print(json.dumps(new_dict))  # {"Test Suite  # 1": ["tc1", "tc2", "tc3"], "Test Suite  # 2": ["tc4", "tc5", "tc6"]}
```

This can be done with `defaultdict` which automatically use what you give as value, here a `list`

```
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data.items():
    for items in value:
        if tc_flag in items:  
            new_dict[key].append(items)
```

You can shorten this with dict-comprehension

```
new_dict = {
    key: [item for item in values if tc_flag in item]
    for key, values in data.items()
}
```

Comment: I think OP's original data dictionary contains list of lists as values (vs. list of strings) e.g. `[["unnecessary"], ["tc2"], ["tc1"], ["tc3"], ["unnecessary"]]` although it's kinda unclear.

Comment: A list of size-1 list of string you mean?